# Message written to SNS topic, but no SQS queue subscribed

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

I'm wondering what would happen if there was an SNS topic having messages written to it, but for a period of time, there is no SQS queue. Let's say there was a container which normally was subscribed to the SNS topic to handle such messages, but it crashed and burned and spent 10 minutes getting resurrected; what would happen to any messages written to that topic, during which there is no queue? Do they disappear forever, or do they wait politely until some queue comes along, subscribes and picks up said messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They disappear forever.

SNS cannot know that some subscriber wants to subscribe but simply cannot right now. The topic either has subscribers or it does not. All current subscriber get the message, all future ones do not.

If you have subscriber but the delivery fails there is some SNS specific behaviour in regards to retries: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-message-delivery-retries.html

Answer (score 0):

If the subscriber fails to get the message, a retry mechanism in SNS kicks in as explained in the [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-message-delivery-retries.html):

> When the delivery policy is exhausted, Amazon SNS stops retrying the delivery and **discards the message**—unless a dead-letter queue is attached to the subscription.

For SQS subscriber retry can  be up to `100,015 times, over 23 days`

Answer (score 0):

If SQS Queue goes down then message won't disappear , Let's discuss this scenario:

**Retry Policy** :-** Let's say you set "Number of retries" as ***n*** and "Retry-backoff function" as ***Linear***(you can select any other retry-backoff function) in SNS topic , then if SQS is not available then SNS will retry to send that message to subscriber(SQS) ***n*** number of times based on the "Retry-backoff function" .

But if you set **Number of retries** as 0 then your message will delete from SNS topic immediately if Subscriber(SQS) is not available